# How do I order the y axis of a matplotlib graph using y-ticks (Monday → Sunday) sorting the data in the process?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm coding a python program that takes data from the past six months and plots them without much input from the user to streamline my reporting process. To do so I have my x-ticks as 0 → 23 in 24-hour time and want to set my y-ticks so that they are ordered by matplotlib to go from Monday(0) → Sunday(6) and sort the plot points in the process because they are fixed in their position.

To sort and format all the data I've used pandas, numpy and datetime. For plotting I'm using matplotlib and numpy. I've been working on this problem for a while and what usually happens is that all the y-ticks sit at one co-ordinate layering all 7 rows into one.

This is my current plotting code:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect=1)
ax.scatter(x,y,s=siz, c=colours, alpha=0.3)
plt.title('Door Logs, Janurary 2019 - Present Day')
plt.xlabel('Hour of Day')
plt.ylabel('Day of Week')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 24, step=1))
```

And my plotting data for 'ax.scatter' is:

x - a numeral representing the hour of the plot point, 0 → 23

y - a string representing the day of the plot point, Monday → Sunday

As outlined previously whenever I try to pre-set my y-ticks I end up with all the rows stacked on top of eachother or with an empty graph.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit some example data from `x` and `y` into the question? Also, does your current plotting code produce a valid graph, and it's only when you try to set y-tick labels that you get overlapping rows and an empty graph?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler my current plotting code outlined above does produce a valid graph when run, I just want to make it a bit easier to read when presented without much context. When I try to set my y-tick labels and use that to order the data is when I get either overlapping rows or an empty graph. Here are a couple of data lines that I pulled from my .csv file that can add some context: 6,7/01/2019,Monday,84,blue
1,1/01/2019,Tuesday,7,blue
13,1/01/2019,Tuesday,3078,skyblue
6,2/01/2019,Wednesday,102,blue
With the first column being the x value and the third column being the y

Answer (score 0):

It could be easier to do this with pandas before extracting the x and y arrays, but here is a numpy-only solution:

### Using NumPy only:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
days = np.array(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])

# Generate some dummy x,y data:
N = 100
np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randint(0,24,N)
y = np.random.choice(days,N)

y_Idx = np.where(days == np.expand_dims(y,-1))[1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, aspect=1)
ax.scatter(x,y_Idx, alpha=0.3)
plt.title('Door Logs, Janurary 2019 - Present Day')
plt.xlabel('Hour of Day')
plt.ylabel('Day of Week')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 24, step=1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(7),days)
plt.show()

# Sorting the data a posteriori if needed:

sorting_idx = np.argsort(y_Idx)
x_sorted = x[sorting_idx]
y_sorted = y[sorting_idx]
```

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwMy2.jpg)

#### Step by step:

Define an array with the sorted days of the week:

`days = np.array(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])`

Search for the index of each element in your `y` array with `np.where` (you must perform the comparison along a new dimension)

`y_Idx = np.where(days == np.expand_dims(y,-1))[1]`

This returns a numerical array (0 to 6) to plot on the y-axis.

`plt.scatter(x,y_Idx)`

Then substitute the numerical labels with strings:

`plt.yticks(np.arange(7),days)`

To sort the data from Monday to Sunday, you can get the sorting indices with:

```
sorting_idx = np.argsort(y_Idx)
x_sorted = x[sorting_idx]
y_sorted = y[sorting_idx]
```